# Null reference exception in xunit test cases: IConfiguration settings

Tags: c#, xunit

I have written a few xUnit tests for API controller methods. I am using the configuration setting from the azure portal app settings.

This is the code I used for initializing the settings.

```
private readonly  IConfiguration _configuration;
public   Controller(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}
```

In the test case class,

```
IConfiguration _configuration;
[Fact]
public async void Method1()
{
    Controller controller = new Controller(_configuration);


}
```

After run the test I am getting an error

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What is the possible solution for this?

Comment: You're passing a null to the constructor, unless you initialize `_configuration` in code you haven't posted

Answer (score 1):

You need to define _configuration.  At the moment you declare the reference, but don't assign an object to it.  It is null.

You need somethine such as :

IConfiguration _configuration = new Configuration();

The above assumes, of course, that Configuration is a class that implements your IConfiguration interface.

Comment: Should a class be created  that implements Iconfiguration?

Comment: @DVV, yes absolutely.   IConfiguration is just an interface.  It describes a contract, but does nothing itself.